# GA total results is significantly less with hour dimension than with date dimension

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using the GA API running two queries over 1 year's worth of data:

Query1:

```
Get apiQuery = analytics.data().ga()
 .get("ga:" + profileId,
 "2013-03-08",
 "2014-03-09",
 "ga:visits")
 .setDimensions("ga:campaign,ga:keyword,ga:date")
 .setSort("ga:campaign,ga:keyword")
 .setFilters("ga:medium==cpc")
 .setMaxResults(1000);
```

Query2:

```
Get apiQuery = analytics.data().ga()
 .get("ga:" + profileId,
 "2013-03-08",
 "2014-03-09",
 "ga:visits")
 .setDimensions("ga:campaign,ga:keyword,ga:date,ga:hour")
 .setSort("ga:campaign,ga:keyword")
 .setFilters("ga:medium==cpc")
 .setMaxResults(1000);
```

The only difference is the extra hour dimension.

The first query returns 651322 results
The second query returns 91592 results

This doesn't make sense to me - I would expect approx 651322*24 = 15M results to be returned.

Does anyone know why this would be?

Thanks for any help,

Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like your data has been sampled.

> [samplingLevel](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#samplingLevel) string no The desired sampling level. Allowed Values:
>
> ```
>  •DEFAULT — Returns response with a sample size that balances speed and accuracy.  
>  •FASTER — Returns a fast response with a smaller sample size. 
>  •HIGHER_PRECISION — Returns a more accurate response using a large sample size, but this may result in the response being slower.
> ```

Note: If I remember right the API should return some variable with your data.  It tells you that the data was sampled: try looking for something like containsSampledData, sampleSize, or sampleSpace. I cant remember which one it is right this minute.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like this was the reason. containsSampledData was the flag and it was marked as true. I think my solution to avoid the sampling will be to pull the data in smaller chunks.

Comment: you should be able to tell it you want HIGHER_PRECISION.  try something like .samplingLevel("HIGHER_PRECISION");  But I wouldn't its going to time out trying to process 15m rows.  If you must you could do a day by day loop storing everything. Instead of trying to select a full years worth of data in one batch.   Just keep an eye on your quota.   15M rows at 10k row chucks gives you 1500 requests you should be good.