# google ga api multiple dimensions value, return less data than I expected

Tags: google-analytics

Possible similar question: [GA total results is significantly less with hour dimension than with date dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22308677/ga-total-results-is-significantly-less-with)
-hour-dimension-than-with-date-dimens
but i use samplingLevel=HIGHER_PRECISION

I am registering my events as follows:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'search_event_category', 'search_term', 'location');
```

category = search_event_category

action = search_term

label = location

I would pull a report via the ga api to return me on the rows the relationship between action and label:

```
["search_event_category",
"search_term",
"location",
"2"]
```

I got this return using the following parameters in the query:

```
metrics=ga:totalEvents
dimensions=ga:eventAction,ga:eventLabel
&filters=ga:eventCategory==search_event_category
&samplingLevel=HIGHER_PRECISION
&start-index=1
&max-results=10000
```

But I realized that the total results is less than I expected:

```
totalsForAllResults": {
"ga:totalEvents": "57623"
}
```

I expected totalEvents 80832. In GA interface, i get this value

when I send  "dimensions=ga:eventAction" i get  *"totalsForAllResults": {"ga:totalEvents": "80832"}*

when I send  "dimensions=ga:eventLabel" i get  *"totalsForAllResults": {"ga:totalEvents": "57623"}*

when I send  "dimensions=ga:eventLabel,ga:eventAction" It looks like it does a 'inner join' and i get *"totalsForAllResults": {"ga:totalEvents": "57623"}*

I'm doing the right way?

## UPDATE 1

I know how difficult without help data, but put here pictures that prove that there is in ga relationship that was not returned by the query

[evidence that the relationship exists in ga](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGi0c.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you're sending events to GA that don't include an event label, then when you query for events and specify the `ga:eventLabel` dimension, events without a label will be dropped from the returned result set. That's the most likely reason for the number discrepancy.

To avoid this problem, I'll sometimes set the event label to "(not set)" to mimic how GA internally indicates that a dimension value is unknown.

Comment: I imagined it, but I have examples that the relationship event x label has been sent correctly, and I can see this relationship in ga interface, but the same was not returned to the query

Comment: For unsampled reports, the only reason that number should be different is due to hits with missing values. If your reports contain sampled data, that could also be the issue. Without knowing exactly what you're seeing, it's impossible to say for sure.

Comment: It should not help much, but added a picture